# How is the equivalent of the English "Let's ..." formed?

Tags: grammar, imperative

I read this part in a book:

[image]

I wonder if this is correct because I always form such sentence like the English "Let's ..." with "lassen" ("lass uns ..."), for example:

> Lass uns gehen
>   Lass uns sehen
>   Lass uns hier setzen

So:

- Which one is correct or more common?
- While searching for the answer in Google, I saw also "Lasst ...", is it another form of "let's ..."?

Comment: Definitiv nicht `Lass uns hier setzen`, sondern entweder `Lass uns hier sitzen` oder `Lass uns uns hier hinsetzen`.

Answer (score 8):

[John Smithers](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/how-is-the-equivalent-of-the-english-lets-formed/3143#3143) is right, you *can* use both,

**BUT**,

"Lass uns..." (addressing one person) or "Lasst uns..." (addressing a group of people) are not colloquial, at least in the southern half of Germany. Again [John Smithers](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/how-is-the-equivalent-of-the-english-lets-formed/3143#3143) is right that the alternative from your book is not very common.

The more I think about it, the more it seems to me that we either paraphrase the entire thing, or, usually, I would actually put it in the question form mentioned above:

> Let's go for a coffee! - Gehen wir einen Kaffee trinken?
>
> Let's go home! - Gehen wir nach Hause?

But:

> Let's see... - Schauen wir mal...

I suppose the latter exception is due to the fact that the entire thing is more or less an idiomatic phrase.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.John Smithers said they're not colloquial as well, is that what you meant or you missed something after but?

Comment: @Gigili: I took "neither of these constructions" to refer to the suggestions in the book and wanted to add that down here the "lassen" derivates are not colloquial, too... :)

Answer (score 4):

Die Phrase »Lass uns ...«, die häufig als Übersetzung für »Let's« angeboten wird, findet sich in letzter Zeit zwar immer häufiger in deutschen Texten, aber sie entsteht eigentlich fast immer aus einer schlechten (weil zu wörtlichen) Übersetzung eines englischen Konstrukts.

Das zeigt auch diese Grafik recht deutlich:
[image: [Google Ngram »Lass uns«]
[Google Ngram »Lass uns«](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lass%20uns&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CLass%20uns%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blass%20uns%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLass%20uns%3B%2Cc0)

Wenn ein deutscher Text Sätze wie

> Lass uns nach draußen gehen.
>   Lass uns tanzen.
>   Lass uns einen Kuchen backen.

enthält, ist das ein deutlicher Hinweis auf eine zu wörtliche Übersetzung aus einer englischen Quelle, oder auf einen Autor, der zu viele solcher schlechten Übersetzungen gelesen hat.

Andererseits muss man angesichts der raschen Verbreitung dieser Konstruktion auch zugeben, dass sie mittlerweile auch als weniger fremd wahrgenommen wird, als das noch in den 1990er-Jahren der Fall war.

Ich persönlich halte diese Phrase nach wie vor für schlechten Stil, und finde, man sollte die Sätze durch Konstruktionen ersetzen, die besser in einen deutschen Kontext passen:

> Gehen wir nach draußen.
>   Wir könnten (doch) nach draußen gehen.
>   Warum gehen wir nicht (einfach/mal) nach draußen.
>
> Willst du mit mir tanzen?
>   Komm, tanz mit mir!
>   Los, tanzen wir!
>
> Wir könnten jetzt mal einen Kuchen backen.
>   Komm, wir backen einen Kuchen.
>   Was hältst du davon, sollen wir einen Kuchen backen?

Die Bedeutungen der angeführten Alternativen entsprechen nicht immer zu genau 100% der »Lass uns«-Variante, man muss daher im konkreten Fall auf die jeweilige Semantik achten, aber diese Sätze enthalten alle das auffordernde Element, etwas gemeinsam zu machen, das im englischen »let's« steckt. Und trotzdem klingen diese Alternativen wirklich nach natürlicher deutscher Sprache.

Aber das englische »let's« hat es auch als Lehnwort schon in den deutschen Wortschaft geschafft:

> Let's fetz!
>   Lets fetz! Letz fetz! <sub>(alternative Schreibweisen)</sub>

Der zitierte Satz fordert auf eine Party zu feiern (also zu fetzen = Feiern bis die Fetzen fliegen), scheint meinen Recherchen zufolge aber in Österreich gängiger zu sein als in anderen Regionen.

Comment: Ich verwende "Lass uns" ständig, ohne dass ich grade einen englischen Text übersetze oder Englisch denke. "Los, tanzen wir" ist wahrscheinlich das letzte, was ich sagen würde. "Komm, tanz mit mir" ist akzeptabel, aber auch noch nie so gesagt. "Willst du mit mir tanzen?" wohl nur zu fremden Frauen. Neben "Komm, lass uns tanzen", wäre noch "Sollen wir tanzen?" gängig, wie du es beim Kuchen-Beispiel angebracht hast. Nichtsdestotrotz, "Lass uns" ist keine zu wörtliche Übersetzung, sondern Alltagssprache.

Comment: @Em1: Wenn du das für Alltagssprache hältst, dann glaube ich, dass es da regionale Unterschiede geben muss. Dort wo ich lebe (Ost-Österreich) tut das nämlich in den Ohren weh und ist alles andere als Alltagssprache.

Comment: Ich muss Hubert recht geben. *Let’s* ist die englische Variante des Imperativs der ersten Person Plural. Als solches sollte man es durch einen Imperativ im Deutschen widergeben.

Comment: @Jan Also müsste es im Deutschen korrekt "Lasst uns" heißen. Das ist ja dann Imperativ Plural. Oh, oh... Lasst uns ab jetzt einfach alles Wort-für-Wort übersetzen, dann wird alles einfacher. (Hier war natürlich "lasst uns" richtig, aber nur weil ich uns alle meine.)

Comment: @Em1 Ich weiß nicht, wie du auf den Schmarrn kommst, aber ich meine selbstverständlich den Imperativ des Verbs das hinter *let’s* steht. *Let’s **stop** this nonesense* → **Hören** wir mit dem Scheiß **auf.**

Comment: @Jan Aha.......sehr formal. Dann bleib ich lieber bei "lass uns", bevor ich noch schräge Blicke ernte.

Comment: Ich habe mal zwei Varianten an das [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lass+uns%2Classt+uns%2Classet+uns&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) angefügt, von denen eine das Ergebnis in einem etwas anderen Licht erscheinen lässt.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that might sometimes sound better is "Wir sollten...".

Comment: Is that a good alternative? I get the impression that the person is putting me under pressure by saying "wir sollten uns treffen", Is it right or I'm under the illusion?

Comment: No, there is some slight pressure. But of course, there always is when someone suggests something that includes you.

Comment: Aha, "there always is when someone suggests something that includes you", great point. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both. I would prefer in most (but not all) cases the construction with "lassen", but that's up to you. As far as I know none of these constructions is colloquial.

First: No-one would say "Studieren wir jetzt". I guess they mean "Lernen wir jetzt". I would use "Lass uns lernen" because the other sentence sounds more like a question to me "Lernen wir jetzt? (Oder können wir noch spielen?)".

Second: The difference between "lass" and "lasst" is the different use of "Du" and "Ihr".

> "He, Du, lass uns nach Hause gehen."
>
> "He, Ihr, lasst uns nach Hause gehen."

("[He](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/he)" is an interjection.)

Answer (score 2):

"Let's" is adhortative mood, of which at least two forms exist in German. The more common form, at least in written language, is formed by Konjunktiv I:

> Seien wir nicht so streng.
>   Schauen wir mal.

The other form with "Lassen" is more common in formal contexts, as it is the only way to mark formality for adhortative mood:

> Lassen Sie uns doch über die Familienpolitik reden.

It is unlikely that it stems from English, as it appears in many Germanic languages. It is, however, likely that English causes it to be used more often.

Johannes Erben in "Lasst uns Feiern" claims that there is a third way to express adhortative mood, with *wollen*:

> Wollen wir uns nun dem Adhortativ zuwenden.

This variant surely is dated.

Personally, I think that *lassen* is more commanding; it should be used if you want to really command others to follow you:

> Lass uns Liebe machen! (song title)
>   ?Machen wir Liebe!

The second sentence just doesn't as much express the desire to have sex right here, right now.

All variants can be reinforced by using *kommen*:

> Komm, lass uns Schwimmen gehen!
>   Komm, gehen wir Schwimmen!
>   Komm, wir wollen Schwimmen gehen!

Apart from that, the adhortative mood is often paraphrased by questions, especially with *sollen*:

> Sollen wir schwimmen gehen?

Comment: *Let’s* is an imperative mood.

Comment: @Jan: *Let* as such, but not the entire construction, which clearly serves as adhortative mood (which is defined as a command/encouragement to others for joint action).

Answer (score 1):

The Yiddish idiom is quite distinctive in this case: "lomir", as in "lomir gehen shlafen", where lomir is a contraction of lass mir, where mir is the first person plural, equivalent to German wir. Technically I suppose it should be lass uns (pr. "loz uns"): I don't know if that's dative or accusitive but nominative is definitely wrong. And yet it's apparently the nominative that is idomatic. No one says "loz uns".

And no, I'm not mixing it up with the first person singular: that would be "loz mich zu ruh", as in "leave me alone". There's also a "lomich"; I'm not sure I'll be able to use it accurately in context, but I think "lomich prubieren" would be "let me give it a try".

Comment: What an informative answer, thank you. What does "pr" stand for?

Comment: I'm gratified that you enjoyed it. The "pr" is for "pronounced". (I like to spell Yiddish according to the German system, but that tends to obscure some of the vowel shifts.)

Answer (score 0):

People will look at you funny if you use the *lassen* versions. Just sayin'

Plus: your book is wrong about *studieren*. That's a common falscher Freund. English "to study" translates into either üben or lernen. Studieren means to major in something.