# Doppeltes Pronomen

Tags: grammar, usage

Nehmen wir mal diese Sätze unter die Lupe:

> Lass uns uns treffen.
>
> Lass mich mich waschen.

etc. Zwar sind diese Sätze korrekt, sie klingen aber in meinen Ohren nicht zwangsläufig schön. Wie ist es nun? Sind sie doch völlig OK? Sollte man solche Sätze meiden? Darf / kann man eins der Pronomen weglassen?

Comment: Eine Alternative, die manchmal funktioniert (und dann häufig präziser ist) ist *einander:* »Lass uns uns treffen.« → »Lass uns einander treffen.«

Comment: Related: [Is “Lass uns uns treffen” correct?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/is-lass-uns-uns-treffen-correct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solche Verdoppelungen versucht man tatsächlich zu vermeiden.

*Lass uns uns treffen* wird meistens so formuliert:

> Lass treffen! (sehr plump, nur unter guten Freunden)
>   Lass uns mal treffen.
>   Lass uns doch (ein)mal treffen.

Bei Gesprächen mit Autoritäten (*Lassen Sie…*) würde ich nur den dritten Satz empfehlen.

Ob und wie man *Lass mich mich waschen* umformuliert, hängt von der intendierten Aussage ab. Unverändert wäre er nur bei einer Situation denkbar, in der das Gegenüber das Badezimmer/Waschbecken spaßeshalber blockiert oder man sonst irgendwie gezielt daran gehindert wird, sich zu waschen. Jedoch würde man hier wohl auch auf einen eleganteren Satz ausweichen:

> Lass mich vorbei!
>   Lass mich ins Badezimmer!
>   Lass mich ans Waschbecken!

Ist der Gesprächspartner ungeduldig, würde man ihn so besänftigen:

> Warte (noch kurz), bis ich mich gewaschen habe.
>   Ich wasche mich nur noch kurz.

Comment: Im Satz `Lass uns mal treffen` hast du tatsächlich das zweite Pronomen einfach weggelassen. Dies entspricht auch dem, was ich bis jetzt immer intuitiv gemacht habe, ohne nachzudenken. Danke für die hilfreiche Antwort.

Comment: @BarthZalewski: Nicht nur dort, sondern auch bei der nächsten Variante mit *doch (ein)mal*. Deshalb klingen sie auch irgendwie merkwürdig bis falsch, eben weil ein Pronomen fehlt und man sofort eine (ebenso unvollständige) Antwort wie "Ok, dann treffen wir." im Kopf hat. Die naheliegendere Ausweichmöglichkeit ohne die unschöne Verdopplung von "uns" ist dann doch eher so was wie "Lass uns mal ein Treffen ausmachen/vereinbaren!" (je nach Förmlichkeitsgrad) oder "Treffen wir uns doch (ein)mal!"

Comment: Auf "Lass mal treffen" oder "Lass uns mal treffen" ist meine Standardantwort: "Wen?". Zudem steht es bei mir sprachlich auf dem gleichen Niveau wie "Ich geh Aldi".

Answer (score 8):

In *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* wird empfohlen, Sätze, in denen zweimal das gleiche Pronomen hintereinander stehen muss, umzuformen, weil sie stilistisch unschön sind.

Beispielsweise muss im folgenden Satz der Akkusativ „mich“ zweimal stehen, denn das erste „mich“ ist das Personalpronomen zu „lassen“ (lass mich [das und das tun]) und das zweite ist das Reflexivpronomen zu „ausdrücken“ (ich drücke mich aus).

> Lassen Sie mich mich etwas freier ausdrücken.

Besser sind

> Gestatten Sie mir, dass ich mich etwas freier ausdrücke.

und

> Lassen Sie mich eine etwas freiere Ausdrucksweise wählen.

um das erste bzw. das zweite „mich“ durch einen anderen Ausdruck zu ersetzen.

Man kann jedoch nicht einfach eines der beiden erforderlichen Pronomina weglassen:

> Lassen Sie mich mich erst anziehen.
>   <s>Lassen Sie mich erst anziehen.</s>