# »Lass uns erkälten« vs. »Lass uns erkältet werden«?

Tags: grammar, reflexive

Ich bin gerade in Russland und wir gingen im bloßen T-Shirt bei minus 25 Grad auf den Balkon und ich sagte:

> Lass uns erkälten!

Meine Freundin meinte, man müsse sagen:

> Lass uns erkältet werden.

Ich meinte, das wäre nicht möglich. Was ist richtig?

Comment: Nimm einfach den isolierenden Adhortativ: *Erkälten wir uns!* Den analytischen Adhortativ halte ich bei reflexiven Verben für unpraktisch, wegen der Frage, was mit dem zweiten "uns" passieren soll.

Comment: "Auf dass wir uns erkälten!"

Comment: Related: [Doppeltes Pronomen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18370/doppeltes-pronomen)

Comment: Also eigentlich finde ich das ganze keine besonders gute Idee ;-) Es sei denn, du kommst direkt aus der Sauna.

Answer (score 4):

Beide sind unüblich, aber (2) ist etwas üblicher.

(1) hat den Nachteil, daß es eigentlich heißen müßte "Laß uns uns erkälten!" Eine solche direkte Wiederholung von Partikeln ist aber allgemein sehr stark dispräferiert. Man hat also entweder ein syntaktisches oder ein euphonisches Problem und keinen guten Ausweg.

(2) ist einigermaßen verständlich, hat aber den Nachteil, daß man eben eigentlich nicht sagt "Ich werde erkältet", sondern "Ich erkälte mich", was aber eines der beiden obengeschilderten Probleme aufwerfen würde.

Es handelt sich also um ein mehrdimensionales Optimierungsproblem, das keine gute Gesamtlösung hat.

Comment: dispräferiert :)

Comment: In (2) muss man *erkältet* als Adjektiv interpretieren.