# Verwendung von "als auch als"

Tags: grammar, usage

> Er arbeitet sowohl als Verkäufer als auch als Taxifahrer.

Dieser Satz klingt etwas umständlich, weil *als* dreimal vorkommt. Wäre es noch grammatikalisch korrekt, das Folgende stattdessen zu schreiben?

> Er arbeitet sowohl als Verkäufer als auch Taxifahrer.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18370/doppeltes-pronomen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nein, es ist nicht möglich. Für alle mehrteiligen Konjunktionen gilt, dass die Präposition wiederholt werden muss:

> Er arbeitet sowohl als Verkäufer als auch als Taxifahrer.
>   Er arbeitet nicht nur als Verkäufer, sondern auch als Taxifahrer.
>   Er arbeitet weder als Verkäufer noch als Taxifahrer.
>   Er arbeitet entweder als Verkäufer oder als Taxifahrer.
>   Er arbeitet zwar als Verkäufer, aber nicht als Taxifahrer.

Vergleiche mit diesem anderen Beispiel:

> Er arbeitet sowohl als Verkäufer als auch auf dem Bau.

Wie du siehst, bezieht sich die Präposition des ersten Teils nicht auf den zweiten Teil. Daher musst du die Präposition wiederholen, ansonsten fehlt sie. Es ist, als würdest du sagen:

> Er arbeitet als Verkäufer. Er arbeitet auch Taxifahrer.

In diesem Satz ist es offensichtlich falsch.

Die „sowohl … als auch“-Struktur erlaubt es dir den redundanten Teil, der vor *sowohl* steht, auszulassen.

> **Er arbeitet** als Verkäufer. **Er arbeitet** (auch) als Taxifahrer.
>   => **Er arbeitet** sowohl als Verkäufer als auch als Taxifahrer.

Man könnte theoretisch auch Folgendes sagen:

> Er arbeitet als beides, Verkäufer und Taxifahrer.

aber zum einen finde ich, dass man hier *als* immer noch wiederholen sollte, und zum anderen funktioniert das nur wirklich als Antwort in einer Unterhaltung.

Aber es gibt noch eine Version mit nur einem *als*:

> Er ist sowohl Verkäufer als auch Taxifahrer.

Comment: So wie _Er war in Berlin und Hamburg_ geht, kann sich auch _als_ auf zwei Teile beziehen, daher würde ich nicht sagen, daß es definitiv ungrammatisch ist.

Comment: @chirlu Ja, "Er war in Berlin und Hamburg" ist richtig. Nein, "Er war sowohl in Berlin als auch Hamburg" empfinde ich falsch. Das hieße, er war in Berlin und war Hamburg. Der Punkt geht trotzdem an dich, weil ich gar nicht weiß, warum das so ist...

Comment: Was ist mit _Er war in sowohl Berlin als auch Hamburg_?

Comment: @chirlu Und schon weiß ich, warum das andere Beispiel funktioniert. "Er war in [Berlin] und [Hamburg]" – "Er war [in Berlin] und [in Hamburg]" --> Das "und" kan sowohl die Präpositionalphrase and auch nur das Nomen verknüpfen. Daher beides möglich. Das geht jedoch nicht bei der "sowohl ... als auch" Phrase, weil der redundante Part vor dem "sowohl" steht. Da käme dein Beispiel aus dem letzten Kommentar in Frage. Das geht soweit ich weiß tatsächlich im Englischen, im deutschen klingt es gruselig. Ist aber glaube ich trotzdem richtig.

Answer (score 4):

Die zweite Variante klingt für Muttersprachler unsauber.

Die Grundform ist ja „arbeiten als etw.“. Das heißt, das „als“ muss definitiv vor die Berufsbezeichnung. Gebräuchlich ist auch „sein“ in Verbindung mit Berufen, d. h., die Alternative zu dem Satz mit drei „als“ wäre:

> Er ist sowohl Verkäufer als auch Taxifahrer.

Natürlich ist der erste Satz mit drei „als“ etwas unschön, aber grammatikalisch richtig. Um das zu vermeiden, müsste man den Satz umformulieren.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist nicht undenkbar (man würde dann das erste *als* auf beide Tätigkeiten beziehen müssen); manche Muttersprachler halten es jedoch für ungrammatisch, und auch für jemanden, der es gerade noch akzeptabel findet, klingt es seltsam. Daher ist es besser, eine andere Verknüpfung zu wählen, etwa so:

> Er arbeitet sowohl als Verkäufer wie auch als Taxifahrer.
>   Er arbeitet als Verkäufer wie auch als Taxifahrer.
>   Er arbeitet als Verkäufer sowie als Taxifahrer.
>   Er arbeitet zugleich als Verkäufer und als Taxifahrer.

Comment: Würdest du bei dem "sowie"- und "zugleich"-Beispiel das zweite "als" eigentlich auch fallen lassen? "Er arbeitet als Verkäufer sowie Taxifahrer", "Er arbeitet zugleich als Verkäufer und Taxifahrer"?

Comment: @Em1: Ich würde sagen, es geht zumindest (und besser als bei _sowohl … als auch_). Bei _und_ ist das fast gar kein Problem mehr: _Er arbeitet als Verkäufer und Taxifahrer._