# (Doppelte) Präposition vor "sowohl ... als auch" ziehen

Tags: conjunction, grammaticality, redundancy

In einer anderen Frage von heute ([Verwendung von “als auch als”](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24967/1224)) wurde sowohl in einem Kommentar als auch in einer Antwort ein Beispiel angeführt, dass die (ansonsten doppeltaufgeführte) Präposition vor "sowohl" zieht.
Als Beispiel hier noch mal mein Einführungssatz mit einer winzigen Änderung:

> In einer anderen Frage [...] wurde in sowohl einem Kommentar als auch einer Antwort ein Beispiel angeführt, [...].

Die Beispiele aus dem anderen Thread:

> Er war in sowohl Berlin als auch Hamburg.
>   Er arbeitet als sowohl Verkäufer als auch Taxifahrer.

Als ich eingangs eine eigene Antwort zu der verlinkten Frage schrieb, habe ich auch schon über diese Struktur nachgedacht, empfand aber, dass das zumindest im dort gegebenen Beispiel nicht wirklich schön klingt. Den Standpunkt vertrete ich immer noch, nur frage ich mich aber auch, ob es nicht sogar falsch ist.

Es gibt zweifelsohne Beispiele, wo das korrekt ist, dort werden dann aber beispielsweise die Adjektive gesowohlt. (Sorry, ich bin grad unfähig, es anders auszudrücken.) Die beiden folgenden Sätze sind für mich absolut in Ordnung.

> Man kann dort in sowohl sommerlichen als auch winterlichen Jahreszeiten schwimmen gehen.
>   Man kann dort sowohl in sommerlichen als auch in winterlichen Jahreszeiten schwimmen gehen.

Anders ist das hier:

> *Man kann dort im sowohl Sommer als auch Winter schwimmen gehen.
>   Man kann dort sowohl im Sommer als auch im Winter schwimmen gehen.

In meinen Augen ist das erste Beispiel falsch und man kann die Präposition nicht entkoppeln.
Gleiches gilt auch für das "Berlin-vs-Hamburg"-Beispiel als auch für das "Verkäufer-vs-Taxifahrer"-Beispiel. Interessanterweise klingt es nicht ganz so falsch in meinem Satz ganz am Anfang. Nur habe ich keine Idee, woran das liegt.

Vielleicht habe ich jetzt auch einfach zu viel darüber nachgedacht.

Deshalb: Kann man die Präposition vorziehen und somit eine Redundanz vermeiden oder muss die Präposition direkt beim Nomen bleiben?

Comment: *Im* ist natürlich speziell, weil es nicht nur eine Präposition, sondern auch einen Artikel enthält.

Comment: @chirlu Das ist mir tatsächlich entgangen. Wobei ich nicht glaube, dass das des Pudels Kern ist. Aber "Man kann dort in sowohl Sommermonaten als auch Wintermonaten..." klingt für mich ähnlich "nicht-ganz-so-falsch" wie der Eingangssatz "in sowohl einem Kommentar als auch einer Antwort". Ich habe aber allmählich ein Gefühl, wo's hingeht. Die Beispiele wo's imho nicht gut klingt, sind diese mit Eigennamen und Berufsbezeichungen. – Mal schauen, was noch so an Input kommt.

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin mir sicher, dass man Präpositionen offiziell nicht vorziehen darf. Es klingt meinem Sprachgefühl nach oft nicht verkehrt, aber manchmal eben doch, und bei solchen Sätzen wie

> Er war in sowohl Berlin als auch Hamburg.

würde ich definitiv einen Satzstellungsfehler ankreiden, da die Regel ist, dass Konjunktionen vor dem Satzglied, das sie mit dem Hauptsatz verbinden, stehen.
(siehe für weitere Informationen übrigens [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/mehrteilig.html) )

> In einer anderen Frage [...] wurde in sowohl einem Kommentar als auch
>   einer Antwort ein Beispiel angeführt, [...].

Ok, klingt erst einmal nicht schlecht, aber wenn ich

> In einer anderen Frage [...] wurde in sowohl einem Kommentar als auch
>   Büchern ein Beispiel angeführt, [...].

schreiben möchte, würde ich auch das "in" vorziehen (ohne etwas an der grammatischen Konstruktion zu verändern), weil es ja "in einem Kommentar" und "in Büchern" heißt. Ich kenne ehrlich gesagt keine Regel in der deutschen Grammatik, die die Richtigkeit dieses Satzes rechtfertigen würde.

"Extremeres" Beispiel:
Wenn ich mich dann zum Singular korrigiere, würde ich das "einem" der Redundanz wegen auch noch herausziehen können:

> In einer anderen Frage [...] wurde in einem sowohl Kommentar als auch
>   Buch ein Beispiel angeführt, [...].

Ich bin absolut für die Vermeidung von Redundanz, aber ich denke in diesem Fall würde man die Sätze dann "kaputt machen". Man nutzt bei dem Vorziehen ja nur die Tatsache aus, dass die Kombination von Eigenschaften wie Kasus, Numerus und Genus zufällig zum gleichen Artikel führen (und natürlich als Voraussetzung zwei mal die gleiche Präposition verwendet wird).

Comment: "Ich war in Berlin und Hamburg" ist doch ein gültiger Satz? Warum sollte dann "Ich war in sowohl Berlin als auch Hamburg" ein ungültiger sein? (Außer, dass es sich zugegebenermaßen grausig anhört)