# Regionale Verbreitung von »Lass uns ...«

Tags: regional

Durch [diesen Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/how-is-the-equivalent-of-the-english-lets-formed/26362#comment-63225) habe ich gelernt, dass es im deutschen Sprachraum offenbar Gegenden gibt, in denen Sätze wie die folgenden zur Alltagssprache gehören:

> Lass uns nach draußen gehen.
>   Lass uns tanzen.
>   Lass uns einen Kuchen backen.

Dort wo ich lebe, in Österreich, würde man diese Sätze zwar verstehen, aber fragende und leicht entsetzte Blicke ernten, wenn man einen Satz mit »Lass uns« beginnen würde. Mit Bestimmtheit kann ich das nur für die östlichen Bundesländer (Kärnten, Steiermark, Burgenland, Niederösterreich, Wien, Oberösterreich) feststellen, bin aber überzeugt davon, dass das in Salzburg, Tirol und Vorarlberg ebenso ist.

Allerdings hätte ich vermutet, dass »Lass uns« im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum so etwas wie Sprachekel hervorruft, was aber offenbar falsch ist. Daher meine Frage:

In welchen Regionen werden die oben zitierten Sätze (und andere, die mit »Lass uns« beginnen) als normal und unauffällig empfunden, und in welchen Regionen würde man freiwillig niemals einen Satz mit dieser Phrase beginnen?

Comment: Schon in deiner anderen Antwort, aber auch hier, bekomme ich den Eindruck, dass die Formulierung "lasst uns" von Österreich aus gesehen als "schlechtes Deutsch" empfunden wird, die zu wörtlichen Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen entstammt. Aus meinen Eindrücken aus Südwestdeutschland halte ich die Formulierung heutzutage (!) keineswegs für normal oder unauffällig, sondern eher absolut veraltet, aber früher vermutlich normales Deutsch. Mein Gefühl ist ähnlich wie bei anderen Formulierungen, die keiner heutzutage so sagt, aber die in synchronisierten Filmen vorkommen ("Wo steckst du?"), ...

Comment: ... könnte aber auch davon kommen, dass die Formulierung in alten Liedtexten wie "Lasst uns froh uns munter sein" und in [Bibeltexten](http://bibeltext.com/genesis/1-26.htm) durchaus auftaucht, aber eben nicht in der heutigen Alltagssprache.

Comment: _Lasset uns beten_. Ich dachte erst, die Frage bezöge sich auf _lass_ (2.Ps) statt _lasst_ (1.Ps).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Dein Eindruck täuscht dich nicht. Das wird in Österreich tatsächlich als schlechtes Deutsch empfunden.

Comment: Also ich (aus Bayrisch-Schwaben, Ü50)) finde diese Formulierung ganz normal, weder veraltet noch schlechtes Deutsch):  _Laß uns gehen_. Wer deklariert, daß das das -- oh, schön -- eine oder andere ist?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Was? Veraltet? Also ich empfinde das als ganz normales, alltägliches Deutsch. Und auch als korrekte Form. Beispiel: *Lass uns doch mal wieder ins Kino gehen!*. Schlimm finde ich sowas wie *Lass mal Kino*. Und aus Interesse: Wie würde man das denn in Österreich formulieren?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Ich bin nicht aus Österreich, sondern aus Südwestdeutschland. Und für mich klingt "Lass uns doch mal wieder ins Kino gehen!" sehr altmodisch. Ich würde "Gehen wir doch mal wieder ins Kino!" oder "Wir könnten doch mal wieder ins Kino gehen." als gebräuchlich empfinden, aber das mag wie gesagt regional unterschiedlich sein.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die Frage nach der Formulierung in Österreich ging nicht an Dich, sondern an den OP. Hätte ich eventuell als eigenen Kommentar schreiben sollen :-) Alle anderen Formulierungen, die Du aufführst, sind natürlich aus meiner Sicht auch super, aber eben auch die *Lass uns* Variante. Und die kenne ich bereits, seit ich (jetzt 40) ein Kind war - ohne vom Denglischen beeinflusst worden zu sein. Was ist mit Dingen wie *Lass uns nicht streiten* oder *Lass (mich) mal sehen*?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: "Ich will nicht mit dir streiten." klingt für mich deutlich natürlicher.  Bei "Lass mich ..." ist es etwas ganz anderes; diese Verwendung von "lassen" im eigentlichen Sinn, etwas nicht zu verhindern, nicht als Aufforderung, etwas zu tun, finde ich auch heutzutage normal.

Comment: Österreichische Varianten (Umgangssprache): »Gemma ins Kino?« (*Gemma* = *gehen wir*) »Magst ins Kino gehn?« »Hast Lust auf Kino?« - Mir fällt gerade auf, dass zumindest ich, das immer als Frage formulieren würde. Vielleicht ist das auch ein Grund, warum »Lass uns« in Österreich so schlecht ankommt: Weil es eine Aufforderung, also so etwas wie ein Befehl, ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich habe mal verschiedene Zeitungskorpora und die Wikipedia-Diskussionen miteinander verglichen:

```
Korpus       Korpusgröße   Anz. Bel.   Häufigkeit
--------------------------------------------------
Österreich   469.356.467        278   1.688.332,62
Braunschweig 201.067.187      1.060     189.686,03
Süddeutsche  577.775.549      2.283     253.077,33
Bonn           3.047.260          9     338.584,44
Zürich       275.981.275        474     582.238,98
Wikipedia    246.009.270       2478      99.277,35
```

Die Spalten stellen die Korpusgröße, die gefundenen Belege und die Häufigkeit dar (Korpusgröße/Belege). Tatsächlich ist der Adhortativ mit *lassen* für Österreich deutlich seltener.
In den Wikipedia-Diskussionen steigt er deutlich an, da das ein Kontext ist, in dem der Adhortativ häufiger nötig ist.

---

**EDIT**
Da in obiger Tabelle unter dem Begriff »Häufigkeit« die Zahl der Korpuswörter pro Belegwort steht, und man unter einer Häufigkeit aber für gewöhnlich den Kehrwert dieser Zahl (also Belegwort pro einer bestimmten Anzahl von Korpuswörtern) versteht, erlaube ich mir dieser Antwort eine zweite Version derselben Tabelle anzufügen, wobei der Wert der letzten Spalte umgekehrt berechnet wurde:

```
Korpus       Korpusgröße  Belege  Belege pro 10 Mio Korpuswörter
----------------------------------------------------------------
Österreich   469.356.467     278    5,9 
Braunschweig 201.067.187   1.060   52,7 
Süddeutsche  577.775.549   2.283   39,5 
Bonn           3.047.260       9   29,5 
Zürich       275.981.275     474   17,2 
Wikipedia    246.009.270   2.478  100,7
```

Comment: Wenn ich das geographisch richtig deute, scheint *lass uns* häufiger verwendet zu werden, je weiter man nach Norden geht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ohne mich streiten zu müssen, halte ich persönlich die verwendete Zahl für aussagekräftiger. Es ist die Anzahl der Wörter, die man im Mittel durchschauen muss, ehe man einen gesuchten Beleg findet - bei "hätte" passiert das natürlich eher als bei "Lass uns". Es hat den Vorteil,k

Comment: @Veredomon *Beide* Zahlen sind aussagekräftig, es hängt wahrscheinlich von der persönlichen Vorliebe ab, welche man bevorzugt ;)