# Table vs bullet style in German

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

I am writing an essay and using a lot of tables to compare data I use.

I would like to rewrite some of them by using bullet style, but I don’t know how to start such sentence in German.

**Original sentence:** In die Tabelle 3. haben wir die Vor- und Nachteile hier mal zusammengestellt.

**My version:** Lassen wir uns die Vor- und Nachteile hier mal zusammenstellen,

What do you think about it? What can I use instead of "lassen"?

Comment: Both sound rather colloquial to me. I'm not sure that was your intention? The feling comes from the usage of "mal", carrying the impression that this is was done without much effort. Also: it's "in der Tabelle, or better "In Tabelle 3 haben wir..."

Comment: *In der Tabelle haben wir Vor- und Nachteile zusammengestellt*

Comment: Even though there is now an accepted answer, I strongly suggest to revise the title, which currently appears to have no connection whatsoever to the actual question asked. The question and its answer will be much easier to find for future users if it is listed with a more meaningful title.

Comment: In bullet lists, you collect (dis)advantages: _zusammenstellen_. In tables, you contrast or compare them: _gegenüberstellen_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

> Im Folgenden sind Vor- und Nachteile zusammengestellt.

or if you don't like the passive structure:

> Im Folgenden geben wir eine Übersicht über die Vor- und Nachteile.

Answer (score 0):

The version with *"Lassen wir uns"* sounds colloquial only in some regions of the German speaking area. There is [a question about this topic](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26379/1487) in German language. So, you can use it in northern regions but you should avoid it in southern regions (like in Austria).

Alternatives are:

- Active voice:

  > Stellen wir hier mal die Vor- und Nachteile zusammen.
- Passive voice:

  - Vorgangspassiv (not the best choice):

    > Hier wurden die Vor- und Nachteile zusammengestellt.
  - Zustandspassiv (this is my preferred version):

    > Hier sind die Vor- und Nachteile zusammengestellt.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments, the particular wording sounds quite colloquial. Yet if you like a dialogue style, the are a few option which are suitable:

> Schauen wir auf die Vor-und Nachteile in einer Übersicht:

> Gucken wir die Vor- und Nachteile an:

> Stellen wir hier kurz die Vor- und Nachteile zusammen:

However in a colloquial context, e. g. in a talk on the topic, your wording is fine. In that context, I recommend to address the audience directly, though:

> Lassen Sie uns kurz die Vor- und Nachteile hier zusammenstellen.

or if you are at 'du' with your audience

> Lasst uns kurz die Vor- und Nachteile hier zusammenstellen